# Sticky Column in Bootstrap 4 That Doesn't Overlap Footer

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sticky

I have a page with multiple columns, a header, and a footer.  I want a column to scroll with the user, but not overlap the footer:

```
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <div id="main" class="clear-top">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="row pl-4 justify-content-between pb-4">
                        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-12 col-sm-12 ">
                         </div>

                         <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-12 col-sm-12 ">
                             ... Main Content ... 
                         </div>

                         <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 p-4 sidebar-container">
                            ... Content I want to Scroll with User ...
                         </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
        </div>
    </footer>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
// General Styling 
html, body{
    height: 100%; 
}

#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
}

#main {
    overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom:150px; /* this needs to be bigger than footer height*/
}

.footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 150px;
    clear:both;
    padding-top:20px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0; 
}
```

I'm using Bootstrap 4, so I've tried adding the `sticky-top` class to the column I want to scroll, however nothing changed.

I've tried changing the `position` of the column to `sticky`, but again nothing seems to change.  Am I adding this to the wrong div?

Comment: For starters i noticed your HTML has several errors: here is a cleaned up version of your html.

https://jsfiddle.net/d75qh3fx/

Comment: `footer` should be inside `body`. columns must be the immediate children of `row`, not the immediate children of parent columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding, you are looking forward to have a sidebar which floats through the content. If that's the case here is the solution. I have used `sticky-top` which sticks your `side-nav` to the top. No need to use any CSS to align your footer to the bottom. You can use bootstrap inbuilt class `d-flex flex-column min-vh-100` to your main container and use `mt-auto` to your footer. This will align your footer to the bottom of the page

```css
.custom-container {
  height: 500vh;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0
}

footer {
  background: yellow
}

#side-nav {
  background: blue;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div id="side-nav">
        <ul class="sticky-top text-center">
          <li><button id=1>Link1</button></li>
          <li><button id=2>Link2</button></li>
          <li><button id=3>Link3</button></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-sm-8 ">
      <div class="custom-container">
        <h2>Content that scrolls</h2>
        <h5>What is Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
          type specimen book it has?</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="mt-auto">footer</footer>
  </body>
</div>
```

Comment: My content in the div that I want to stay put is in a `row`.  Can I apply `sticky-top` to the row?

Comment: Create a wrapper for your content and apply `sticky-top` to it

Comment: I also had to remove `overflow: auto` from my `#main` div